# exchange management shell script to find changes on mailbox?

Tags: exchange, powershell-v3.0

I have a question to you.I have a mailbox account in my exchange server 2016 which is used a smtp address for while.and now, because of changing its alias and smtp address, is there a way to find the log of the mailbox via exchange management shell to know when this smtp address changing has done?
Thank You

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can use [admin audit log](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd335052(v=exchg.141).aspx) to find out who change the SMTP address for this mailbox. For example:

```
Search-AdminAuditLog -Cmdlets Set-Mailbox -Parameters  PrimarySmtpAddress,EmailAddresses,WindowsEmailAddress -StartDate 11/10/2017 -EndDate 11/16/2015 -IsSuccess $true
```

Note: By default, audit logging is configured to store audit log entries for 90 days. After 90 days, the audit log entry is deleted.